# How to change CSS based on Season using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html, dynamic

I'm sorry if this is a simple question, but I need help on this.  I am trying to create a 'Dynamic' page that will change the look of the page / site with each season (based on Southern Hemisphere Seasons). I have Colors, Headers, Images and backgrounds set in CSS that I want to change when it is Summer, Winter, Autumn and Spring as well as an added feature for DAY Specific Christmas and New Years. I have included the in-line JavaScript from my page, along with the CSS related. Could someone please help, because it is not working!!!

```
<script>
        // JavaScript Document
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var d = new Date();
        var m = d.getMonth();
        var n = d.getDate();
        if ( m >= 3 && m <= 5 )
        (
            // If date is between March and May inclusive, apply autumn theme to ‘body’
            document.body.className = "autumn";
        )
        else if ( m >= 6 && m <= 8 )
        (
            // If date is between June and August inclusive, apply winter theme to ‘body’
            document.body.className = "winter";
        )           
        else if ( m >= 9 && m <= 11 )
        (
            // If date is between September and November inclusive, apply spring theme to ‘body’
            document.body.className = "spring";
        )
        else if( m >= 12 && m <= 2 )
        (
            // All other times apply the 'Summer' theme to 'body'
            document.body.className = "summer";

            if ( m = 12 && n >= 13 && n <= 27 )
            (
                // If date is between 13/12 and 27/12 inclusive, apply Christmas theme to ‘body’
                document.body.className = "xmas";
            )
            else if ( m = 12 && n >= 28 && n <= 31 )
            (
                // If Date is between 28/12 and 31/12 New Year's theme to ‘body’
                document.body.className = "nye";
            )   
            else if ( m = 1 && n >= 1 && n <= 4 )
            (
                // If Date is between 28/12 and 31/12 New Year's theme to ‘body’
                document.body.className = "nye";
            )
        )   
        });

    </script>
```

This is the CSS:

```
    @charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

/* Seasonal Backgrounds */
.winter {
    background-image: url(../images/summer.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
.summer {
    background-image: url(../images/winter.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
.autumn {
    background-image: url(../images/autumn.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
.spring {
    background-image: url(../images/spring.png);
    background-size: cover;
}
.xmas {
    background-image: url(../images/christmas2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
.nye {
    background-image: url(../images/nye2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}

/*Seasonal H2 */
.winter #mainBody h2 {
    background-image: url(../images/headingorange.png);
    color: #ffffff;
}
.autumn #mainBody h2 {
    background-image: url(../images/headingmagenta.png);
    color: #ffffff;
}
.spring #mainBody h2 {
    background-image: url(../images/headinggreen.png);
    color: #ffffff;
}
.summer #mainBody h2 {
    background-image: url(../images/heading.png);
    color: #ffffff;
}
.xmas #mainBody h2 {
    background-image: url(../images/headingorange.png);
    color: #ffffff;
}
.nye #mainBody h2 {
    background-image: url(../images/headingnye.png);
    color: #ffffff;
}

/* Seasonal Tables */
/* Internet Tables */
.winter #Internet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL2.png);
    font: 16px "Segoe UI Light";
    width: 125px;
}
.summer  #Internet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL2.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
    border: none;
}
.autumn  #Internet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/MagentaL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.spring  #Internet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/GreenL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.nye  #Internet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.xmas  #Internet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
/* Intranet Tables */
.winter #Intranet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL2.png);
    font: 16px "Segoe UI Light";
    width: 125px;
}
.summer  #Intranet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL2.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.autumn  #Intranet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/MagentaL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.spring  #Intranet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/GreenL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.nye  #Intranet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.xmas  #Intranet table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
/* Miscellaneous Tables */
.winter #Misc table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL2.png);
    font: 16px "Segoe UI Light";
    width: 125px;
}
.summer  #Misc table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL2.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.autumn  #Misc table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/MagentaL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.spring  #Misc table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/GreenL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.nye  #Misc table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.xmas  #Misc table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
/*Web Apps Tables */
.winter #webApps table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL2.png);
    font: 16px "Segoe UI Light";
    width: 125px;
}
.summer  #webApps table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL2.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.autumn  #webApps table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/MagentaL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.spring  #webApps table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/GreenL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.nye  #webApps table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}
.xmas  #webApps table tr td {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL1.png);
    font: 16px  "Segoe UI Light";
    color: #DDDDDD;
    width: 125px;
}

/*Seasonal Footers */
.winter #footer {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL1.png);
    color: #ddd;
}
.summer #footer {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL1.png);
    color: #ddd;
}
.autumn #footer {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/MagentaL1.png);
    color: #ddd;
}
.spring #footer {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL1.png);
    color: #ddd;
}
.xmas #footer {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL1.png);
    color: #ddd;
}
.nye #footer {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/BlueL1.png);
}

/* Seasonal Headers */
.winter #header {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #001E82;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    background-image: url(../images/headerorange.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align:central;
    height: 69px;
    text-indent:5px;
}
.summer #header {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #001E82;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    background-image: url(../images/header.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align:central;
    height: 69px;
    text-indent:5px;
}
.autumn #header {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #001E82;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    background-image: url(../images/headermagenta.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align:central;
    height: 69px;
    text-indent:5px;
}
.spring #header {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #001E82;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    background-image: url(../images/headergreen.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align:central;
    height: 69px;
    text-indent:5px;
}
.nye #header {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #001E82;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    background-image: url(../images/headernye.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align:central;
    height: 69px;
    text-indent:5px;
}
.xmas #header {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 960px;
    background-color: #001E82;
    color: #D3D3D3;
    background-image: url(../images/headerxmas.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    vertical-align:central;
    height: 69px;
    text-indent:5px;
}

/* Standard CSS */
#nbnEquipSetup a {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL3.png);
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
#nbnEquipSetup {
    background-image: url(../images/Buttons/Metro/OrangeL3.png);
    color: #000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**Sorry for the lengthy post.**

Comment: Can you please expand upon "not working!!!" :) tell us what is not working - what errors you get, what you expected to see instead etc?

Comment: Months are zero indexed, June to August inclusive is `(m >=5 && m <= 7)`. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that months are zero indexed so January is 0, February 1 and so on so December is 11. Pretty easy to fix, just add 1 to the month number returned by *getMonth*.

The code can be greatly simplified since you don't really need the *else* part. Each *if* returns a discrete value, so just use a sequence of ifs. Also, the season can be determined by dividing the month number by 3 and using the modulus operator:

```
// Return the southern hemisphere season for a date
// If no date provided, uses current system date
function getSeason(d) {
  d = d || new Date();
  var mon = d.getMonth() + 1;  // Adjust to be indexed from 1
  var day = d.getDate();
  var seasons = ['summer','autumn','winter','spring'];

  // Do silly seasons here
  if (mon == 12) {
    if (day >= 13 && day <= 27) {
      return 'xmas';
    }
    if (day >= 28 && day <= 31) {
      return 'nye';
    }
  }

  // If wasn't a silly season, do others
  mon = Math.floor((mon % 12) / 3);
  return seasons[mon];
}

console.log('Currently it is ' + getSeason()); // Currently it is summer
```

Then:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  document.body.className = getSeason();
});
```

Comment: RobG - thanks for this, but I have a problem... it is not working in IE8. As strange as it may sound, I need it to work in this browser. Works fine in IE10 and Chrome, but not IE8.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure what "it" is, I've tested the above function in IE 6 and it works. It doesn't use any ES5 features so it should work in every browser since IE/NN 4.

Comment: "it" is the code :) Thanks again though. This has been a GREAT help! I am currently working on an ONLINE Web Design & Dev Course, and I wanted to make this "Dynamic" page / site that changes with the Season.

Comment: Seasons don't always start on the first day of the month?

Comment: @Kokodoko—that part of the algorithm is the OPs, I don't necessarily agree with it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to change your 'if-else' condition from

```
if ( m >= 3 && m <= 5 )
(
    /* your code */
)else if(...)
(
    /* your code */
)
```

to

```
if ( m >= 3 && m <= 5 )
{
    /* your code */
}else if(...)
{
    /* your code */
}
```

for every 'if-elseif' conditions because it's syntax error.

And you need to increase month('m') variable by 1 because d.getMonth() returns array index like this

```
var m = d.getMonth() + 1;
```

And in the month condition, I think your condition is wrong

```
else if( m >= 12 && m <= 2 )
```

m can't be highter than 12 and less than 2 at the same time so

```
else if( m >= 12 || m <= 2 )
```

Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

`m >= 12 && m <= 2` is impossible. A number can't be greater than 11 and less than 3 at the same time. Perhaps you meant `||` instead of `&&`, but considering it's your last statement you don't need a condition at all. Just use `else`. And you need to enclose your statements with curly braces if they span more than 1 line:

```
if ( condition ) {
  // 1st line
  // second line
}
```